# Ways to parse JSON in LaTeX?

Tags: luatex, parsing, json

I'm writing my recipes (food) in a small textfile in JSON. Are there any ways to parse this in LaTeX?
I know, that are lots of templates dealing with recipes, but I want to have my own style, which can be change very fast e.g. my mother is not interested in stuff like calories :)

Here is one simple example:

```
{
"recipe": {
    "title":"First recipe",
    "source":"My first cookbook",
    "carbs":"1 oz",
    "fat":"1 oz",
    "protein":"1 oz",
    "cal":"100 kcal",
    "ingredients": [
        {"item":"Eggs"},
        {"item":"Oil"},
        {"item":"Nuts"}
    ],
    "cooking": [
        {"step":"Mix eggs and oil"},
        {"step":"Add nuts"}
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2012/10/latex-and-template-engines-revisited/ ?

Comment: In order to help the readers, it would be useful to know if **all** recipes must have entries for all these keywords, or if some may be missing from some recipes.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes JSON has an exceptionally simple grammar, see the railroad diagrams at http://www.json.org/

Comment: I note the json.org lists a lua parser for json. is lualatex a possibility? to save writing the parser in tex?

Comment: I see.  The recipe is merely an example of something to parse.

Comment: Please excuse this self-plug and non-TeX answer: I too store my recipes in JSON, but I built a small website so they are more interactive. Check it out: [live site](https://jessexknight.github.io/foodbook/#quinoa-beet-salad), and [source code](https://github.com/jessexknight/foodbook). Feel free to fork (no pun intended!) and adapt as you like :)

Answer (score 24):

Although the question is about parsing JSON in LaTeX, since the OP wants to *"have my own style, which can be change very fast"*, I'll give a ConTeXt solution for its simplicity.

ConTeXt already comes up with a parser for JSON. To use it, simply load

```
\usemodule[json]
```

Then, you can use the Lua function `utilities.json.tolua`  to convert JSON string to Lua table and the Lua function `utilities.json.tostring` to convert a Lua table to a JSON string.

It is very simple to typeset Lua tables using [ConTeXt Lua Document](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/CLD). Here is a complete example:

```
\usemodule[json]
\startluacode

  userdata = userdata or {}
  local json = utilities.json

  userdata.show_recipe = function(recipe)

  local lua_recipe  = json.tolua(recipe).recipe
  local ingredients = lua_recipe.ingredients
  local cooking     = lua_recipe.cooking

  context.subject(lua_recipe.title)

  local show_value = function(value)
    context.NC() context(value) 
    context.EQ() context(lua_recipe[value])
    context.NC() context.NR()
  end

  context.starttabulate()
    show_value("source")
    show_value("carbs")
    show_value("protein")
    show_value("cal")
  context.stoptabulate()

  context.subsubject("Ingredients")
  context.startitemize{"packed, intro"}
  for i = 1,#ingredients do
    context.startitem()
    context(ingredients[i].item)
    context.stopitem()
  end
  context.stopitemize()

  context.subsubject("Cooking")
  context.startitemize{"packed, intro"}
  for i = 1,#cooking do
    context.startitem()
    context(cooking[i].step)
    context.stopitem()
  end
  context.stopitemize()

  end
\stopluacode
```

Now you can simply define a TeX macro to pass its argument to the Lua function.

```
% Note that I use the braces around #1 to make the input
% syntax slightly simpler
\define[1]\Recipe
    {\ctxlua{userdata.show_recipe([==[{#1}]==])}}
```

Let's add some minimal styling to format the section heads. As with all ConTeXt documents, you can change the format by using appropriate `\setup...` command.

```
\setuphead[subject][style=\bfb]
\setuphead[subsubject][style=\bfa]
```

Finally, the main document

```
\starttext

\Recipe
    {
      "recipe": {
          "title":"First recipe",
          "source":"My first cookbook",
          "carbs":"1 oz",
          "fat":"1 oz",
          "protein":"1 oz",
          "cal":"100 kcal",
          "ingredients": [
              {"item":"Eggs"},
              {"item":"Oil"},
              {"item":"Nuts"}
          ],
          "cooking": [
              {"step":"Mix eggs and oil"},
              {"step":"Add nuts"}
          ]
      }
    } 

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: One of a nice suggestion....

Answer (score 18):

<sub>As always, I missed David's comment, so my idea is not 100% original. `:)` As David said in the chatroom, he subliminally gave me a hint, which proves his powers are beyond comprehension, and that ducks aren't noted for their powers of comprehension normally. `:)`</sub>

> [image: Warning] **Attention:** Although my answer works, please favour Yiannis' answer since it uses a module from the standard `lualibs` available in LuaTeX.

I'll provide a naive answer using LuaTeX just to get things working as quickly as possible. `:)`

First things first: get this [simple JSON encoder/decoder written in pure Lua](http://regex.info/blog/lua/json) from Jeffrey Friedl's site. The file is self-contained and it's named `JSON.lua`. Save to your working directory.

> *Jeffrey's code is released under a Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported License.*

At the very same level, save your JSON file as, say, `recipes.json`:

```
{
    "recipe": {
        "title":"First recipe",
        "source":"My first cookbook",
        "carbs":"1 oz",
        "fat":"1 oz",
        "protein":"1 oz",
        "cal":"100 kcal",
        "ingredients": [
            {"item":"Eggs"},
            {"item":"Oil"},
            {"item":"Nuts"}
        ],
        "cooking": [
            {"step":"Mix eggs and oil"},
            {"step":"Add nuts"}
        ]
    }
}
```

At last, but not least, our TeX file (e.g, `recipes.tex`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}

\begin{luacode}
function read(file)
    local handler = io.open(file, "rb")
    local content = handler:read("*all")
    handler:close()
    return content
end
JSON = (loadfile "JSON.lua")()
local table = JSON:decode(read("recipes.json"))
tex.print(table['recipe']['title'])
\end{luacode}

\end{document}
```

Run your file with

```
$ lualatex recipes.tex
```

The result:

[image: Recipe]

Enjoy! `:)`

Comment: There is a json parser avaialable with "lualibs-util-jsn.lua", just require it:)

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: it is? Oh my, I'm a silly duck! `:)` Let me try here and I will update the answer. Thanks, Yiannis! `:)`

Comment: @Yiannis: You were absolutely right, there is a JSON parser in LuaLibs! `:)` Sadly, I cannot load it (according to the documentation, it's in the "extended set"), even after trying a couple of settings. Do you know how we could use it?

Comment: I will post a minimal

Comment: @PauloCereda  This works on my home machine (windows), with the latest Lua distribution. I am curious to see if it works on Linux.

Comment: I want to use json file inside latex and I tried your code. But it gives error related with Luatex?

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.json}
{
"recipe": {
    "title":"First recipe",
    "source":"My first cookbook",
    "carbs":"1 oz",
    "fat":"1 oz",
    "protein":"1 oz",
    "cal":"100 kcal",
    "ingredients": [
        {"item":"Eggs"},
        {"item":"Oil"},
        {"item":"Nuts"}
    ],
    "cooking": [
        {"step":"Mix eggs and oil"},
        {"step":"Add nuts"}
    ]
}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}



\begin{luacode}
--  We use the lualibs built-in modules
--  this loads all the modules including a json converter
--

local M = M or {}

require("lualibs.lua")


-- @json file
function getjsonfile (file)
    local f, s
      f = io.open(file, 'r')
        s = f:read('*a')
        f.close()
        return s
 end

local s =  utilities.json.tolua(getjsonfile('test.json'))


local rep, write = string.rep, tex.print

function M.inspect (tab, offset)
   local openbracket, closebracket, par = "\\{", "\\mbox{..}\\}", "\\par"

    offset = offset or ""
    for k, v in pairs (tab) do
        local newoffset = offset .. "\\mbox{~~}"
        if type(v) == "table" then
           write(offset .. k .. " = " .. openbracket .. par)
           M.inspect(v, newoffset)
           write(offset .. closebracket .. par)
        else
         if k~="data" then write(offset..k.." =  ".. tostring(v), "\\par") 
           else
                 write(offset.."k = char data ")
           end
       end
    end
end

tex.print(M.inspect(s))
 \end{luacode} 

 \end{document}
```

It should give you this:

[image]

The formatting is done using an inspect method that uses an `\mbox{~~}` to space the brackets out.

Comment: Does the lualibs module load the same JSON parser that is included as `util-jsn.lua` in the ConTeXt distribution?

Comment: @Aditya  It is very simialr https://github.com/phi-gamma/lualibs. They are based on the ConTeXt ones.

Comment: @Aditya It’s the same code, just not updated as frequently.

Comment: The example is broken with TL 2020 (LuaHBTex 1.12.0) : [\directlua]:15: bad argument #1 to 'close' (FILE* expected, got no value)
stack traceback:
 [C]: in field 'close'
 [\directlua]:15: in function 'getjsonfile'
 [\directlua]:19: in main chunk.
\luacode@dbg@exec ...code@maybe@printdbg {#1} #1 }
                                                  
l.77  \end{luacode}

Answer (score 3):

Here are up to date examples that do work with TeX Live 2020 (LuaHBTeX 1.12.0).
The first one is inspired by Paulo cerreda's answer but do not rely on an external tool.
If you have a `test.json` file containing the OP recipe next to your tex document, then

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
% !TEX program = Lualatex

\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode}
require("lualibs.lua")
local f = io.open('test.json', 'r')
local s = f:read('*a')
f:close()
tab =  utilities.json.tolua(s)
\end{luacode} 
\luadirect{tex.sprint(tab['recipe']['title'])}
\end{document}
```

will typeset into "First recipe". Notice that `tab` is a global Lua variable that can be accessed later on.

The second example comes from Yiannis Lazarides answer, it has been fixed and simplified to help Lua beginners but gives the same output.

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
% !TEX program = Lualatex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.json}
{
"recipe": {
    "title":"First recipe",
    "source":"My first cookbook",
    "carbs":"1 oz",
    "fat":"1 oz",
    "protein":"1 oz",
    "cal":"100 kcal",
    "ingredients": [
        {"item":"Eggs"},
        {"item":"Oil"},
        {"item":"Nuts"}
    ],
    "cooking": [
        {"step":"Mix eggs and oil"},
        {"step":"Add nuts"}
    ]
}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode}
local f = io.open('test.json', 'r')
local s = f:read('*a')
f:close()
require("lualibs.lua")
local tab =  utilities.json.tolua(s)
local openbracket = "\\{"
local closebracket = "\\mbox{..}\\}"
local par = "\\par"
local prettyprint
prettyprint = function (tab, prefix)
  for k, v in pairs (tab) do
    local newprefix = prefix .. "\\mbox{~~}"
    if type(v) == "table" then
      tex.print(prefix .. k .. " = " .. openbracket .. par)
      prettyprint(v, newprefix)
      tex.print(prefix .. closebracket .. par)
    elseif k == "data" then
      tex.print(prefix.."k = char data ")
    else
      tex.print(prefix..k.." =  ".. tostring(v), "\\par") 
    end
  end
end
prettyprint(tab, '')
\end{luacode} 
\end{document}
```

**Nota Bene**: there was a faulty `f.close()` in Yiannis' answer.