# luacode error: LuaTex is required for this package

Tags: luatex

I am a new bie to Tex and when i try to run the sample code given in the posting [Ways to parse JSON in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/222604/5001), i run into the error:

> Package luacode Error: LuaTeX is required for this package. Aborting..

i know, this is rudimentary, but how to install LuaTeX package on a ubuntu 14.04 machine?

Comment: now, i tried lualatex file_name, and there are no errors. thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001), by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably already installed. You may have used (La)TeX (or pdf(La)TeX or Xe(La)TeX on a file that requires Lua(La)TeX. If you use the command line, try something like `luatex myfile.tex` or `lualatex myfile.tex`.