# Load fields from JSON file using LuaLatex

Tags: luatex, parsing, luacode, json

I want to load a lot of numbers in my document from a single JSON file that is returned from a simulation. To do that I so far followed [this stackexchange answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/222681) but for multiple values I would have to load the JSON file several times throughout the documents (I am new to LuaLatex so maybe I am missing something essential). What I want is something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}

\begin{luacode}
function read(file)
    local handler = io.open(file, "rb")
    local content = handler:read("*all")
    handler:close()
    return content
end
JSON = (loadfile "JSON.lua")()
local table = JSON:decode(read("recipes.json"))
\end{luacode}

The fat content of the recipe \directlua{tex.print(table['recipe']
['title'])} is \directlua{tex.print(table['recipe']
['fat'])}.

\end{document}
```

What is the cleanest way to achieve that?

Comment: Have you read the warning in the linked answer and tried the other one (from Yiannis)?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer: in the example above the relevant variable (table) is defined as local. That's why it is not accessible in subsequent lua calls. The solution is thus

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}

% load json file
\begin{luacode}
function read(file)
    local handler = io.open(file, "rb")
    local content = handler:read("*all")
    handler:close()
    return content
end
JSON = (loadfile "JSON.lua")()
table = JSON:decode(read("recipes.json"))
\end{luacode}

The fat content of the recipe \directlua{tex.print(table['recipe']
['title'])} is \directlua{tex.print(table['recipe']
['fat'])}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to expand on the answer of @user45893 after doing my own tests based on this question and [the linked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222604/ways-to-parse-json-in-latex) one.

1. The `luacode`-environment can go in the preamble which allows to create custom commands below it to reduce verbosity when you need to print a lot of external values in the document.
2. You can format numbers using the lua function `string.format()` which uses the [c++ printf syntax](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/). However,
3. The command `\directlua{}`does not escape `%` signs so it would require to use the command `\luaexec{}` from the package `\usepackage{luatextra}` instead. This package already includes the `luacode`environment.
4. The given solution uses an external file `JSON.lua` which I couldn't find. A dependency-free solution is the function `utilities.json.tolua()`.
5. The `luacode`-environment accepts LaTeX-commands. For example to describe paths. This allows to easily load multiple files into multiples variables from a same directory.

My finished MWE looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\newcommand{\dataPath}{path/to/folder}

% load the data file supposedly containing 'title' and 'numbers'
\begin{luacode}
  require("lualibs.lua")
  local f = io.open('\dataPath/file.json', 'r')
  local s = f:read('*a')
  f:close()
  data =  utilities.json.tolua(s)
\end{luacode}

% Simple print function
\newcommand{\printlua}[1]{\luaexec{tex.sprint(#1)}}

% Example: formatting a number with an optional formatting argument
\newcommand{\printnumber}[2][i]{\printlua{string.format("\%#1", #2)}}

\begin{document}
Simple print function: \printlua{data['title']}.

% '%i' for signed integer (default of the command).
Default number format: \printnumber{data['numbers']['number1']}. 

% '%.2f' for decimal float with 2 digits after the decimal point .
Different number format: \printnumber[.2f]{data['numbers']['number1']}.
\end{document}
```

Caveats:

- The method is fairly limited for list elements. I only found a way to call them by their explicit index: f.e. `printnumber{data['listofnumbers'][5]}`.
- The formatting of scientific notation (`%e`) returns f.e. `3.9265e+2` which is very ugly in LaTeX math mode. For very large of small numbers, I would recommend additionally storing them as pre-formatted string in the data file when it is generated, and use this solution to load those directly with `\printlua{}`.
- The command `luaexec{}` (or `tex.sprint()`, I am not sure which is the cause) does not simply return the value but embeds it in a group. This hinders further format-processing of the values by other LaTeX-commands.

For example the `\num{}`-command of the `siunitx`-package:

```
\num{\printnumber[.2e]{data['numbers']['number1']}}
% gives:
% Package siunitx Error: Invalid number '\begingroup \escapechar 92...
```

Note: I do not have any experience in lua, please feel free to edit formatting according to usual code conventions.