# LaTeX3 - Read Json as Input in LaTeX3

Tags: latex3, json

I would like to generate LaTeX template based on `JSON` Input. It is possible to take `JSON` as input in `LaTeX3` and create LaTeX template? I had the solutions are found in `LuaLaTeX`.

[Ways to parse JSON in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222604/ways-to-parse-json-in-latex)

How do achieve this in LaTeX3? My `JSON` Input is below:

```
{
    "LaTeXPage": {
        "obj": "LaTeXPage",
        "pro": {
            "paperWidth": {
                "property": "paperWidth",
                "value": "129",
                "units": "mm",
                "remarks": null
            },
            "paperHeight": {
                "property": "paperHeight",
                "value": "198",
                "units": "mm",
            },
            "topMargin": {
                "property": "topMargin",
                "value": "3",
                "units": "mm",
            },
        }
    }
    }
```

Expected LaTeX Package output:

```
\setlength{\paperwidth}{129mm}
\setlength{\paperheight}{198mm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{3mm}
```

Especially i would like to use `expl3` LaTeX Package. Or anyother solutions also welcome!!!

Comment: Why don't you use LuaLaTeX and a real JSON parser library?

Comment: @TeXnician: I have knowledge in `LaTeX` only and i'm new in `LuaLaTeX`. So i would like to do in `LaTeX`. Any solution greatly appreciate.

Comment: @TeXnician: I had tried many ways and not found the solution. Could you please provide `LuaLaTeX` solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatextra} % luacode
\usepackage{environ}  % LaTeX Stylefile Writing in NewEnvironment

% load json file
\begin{luacode*}
function read(File)
    local handler = io.open(File, "rb")
    local content = handler:read("*all")
    handler:close()
    return content
end

JSON = (loadfile "JSON.lua")()
tab = JSON:decode(read("sample.json"))
\end{luacode*}

\newcommand*\JSONpagewidth{\directlua{tex.print(tab['LaTeXPage']['pro']['pageWidth']['value'])}\directlua{tex.print(tab['LaTeXPage']['pro']['pageWidth']['units'])}}

\newwrite\writer
\NewEnviron{styleFileWrite}
    {\immediate\write\writer{%
    \string\setlength\paperwidth{\JSONpagewidth}^^J%
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}
    }}
\immediate\openout\writer=LaTeX-\jobname.sty    
\begin{styleFileWrite}
\end{styleFileWrite}
\immediate\closeout\writer

\begin{document}

Pagewidth values is ::  {\JSONpagewidth}

\end{document}
```