Help with generating invoices from JSON data using LaTeX
I'm looking for help with creating a LaTeX template that can generate invoices from a JSON file. The JSON file contains customer-specific data, such as payee information, items sold, and general details, but the layout of the invoice remains the same.
Here's an example of what the JSON file might look like:
{
  "payee": {
    "name": "John",
    "surname": "Doe",
    "title": "Mr.",
    "address": "123 Main St, Anytown, USA"
  },
  "items_sold": [
    {
      "item_ref_code": "ABC123",
      "item_quantity": 2,
      "item_unit_price": 10.99,
      "item_description": "Widget A (standard model)"
    },
    {
      "item_ref_code": "DEF456",
      "item_quantity": 1,
      "item_unit_price": 5.99,
      "item_description": "Gadget B (deluxe edition)"
    }
  ],
  "general_details": {
    "taxation": "20",
    "my_bank_name": "The Bank Name" ,
    "my_bank_IBAN": "1234567890"   
  },
  "invoice_number": "001",
  "date": "2023-02-20",
  "Due by": "2023-03-20"
}

I'd like to use LaTeX to generate a clean and professional-looking invoice that includes the following elements:
Payee information (name, surname, title, address)
List of items sold with quantities and unit prices
Subtotal, tax, and total amounts
General details (taxation, bank details)
Invoice number and date
I'm familiar with LaTeX basics, but I'm not sure how to parse the JSON data and perform calculations (e.g., subtotal, tax, total) within the LaTeX template.
Can anyone provide guidance on how to achieve this? I'd appreciate any examples or pointers to relevant packages or documentation.

You have two separate issues: (1) how to read a JSON file from within a TeX file and access that data; (2) how to format that data into a clean and professional-looking invoice.  (2) is off-topic as written because it's too opinion based.  We would need to see some sort of desired output.  But (1) (and performing calculations) is on-topic.

"perform calculations (e.g., subtotal, tax, total) within the LaTeX template." Have a look at how https://ctan.org/pkg/zugferd does the calculations

for parsing json: https://ctan.org/pkg/jsonparse

IMHO best option is to use LuaLaTeX and lualibs json parser, see this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/222691/963 is not for an invoice but can easily be modified for invoices.

Living in paradise ? Where are the tax rates ... ?

@MS-SPO, here in paradise we have 19% (general_details": {
"taxation": "20"})

You could make use of the jsonparse package, but you should also have a look at the JSON parser built into LuaLaTeX.
Some notes of warning regarding the jsonparse package:

I am the author 
it is quite new, so there might be some bugs in the code
tabs in the JSON source are only parsed properly as from version 0.9.3
it is not as quick as the JSON parser provided by the Lua interface of LuaLaTeX

Assuming that the code you provided above is stored in a file named invoicedata.json in the same directory as your .tex file, this could serve as a starting point:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}
\usepackage{jsonparse}

\JSONParseFromFile{\invoicedata}{invoicedata.json}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \ListMapInline \clist_map_inline:nn

\prop_new:N \g_marco_invoice_prices_prop
\fp_new:N \l_marco_invoice_total_fp
\NewDocumentCommand { \ItemTotal } { m m } {
    \prop_gput:Nnn \g_marco_invoice_prices_prop 
        {#1} { \fp_eval:n {#2} } 
    \fp_eval:n {#2}
}
\NewDocumentCommand { \InvoiceTotal } { } {
    \fp_zero:N \l_marco_invoice_total_fp
    \prop_map_inline:Nn \g_marco_invoice_prices_prop {
        \fp_add:Nn \l_marco_invoice_total_fp {##2}
    }
    \fp_use:N \l_marco_invoice_total_fp
}
\NewDocumentCommand { \NewlineOrRule } { m m } {
    \int_compare:nNnTF {#1} = {#2} { 
        \\ \midrule
    } {
        \\ 
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    
    \bigskip
    
    \JSONParseValue{\invoicedata}{payee.title} 
    \JSONParseValue{\invoicedata}{payee.name} 
    \JSONParseValue{\invoicedata}{payee.surname}
    
    \JSONParseValue{\invoicedata}{payee.address}
    
    \vspace*{2cm}
    
    \noindent
    Invoice No. \JSONParseValue{\invoicedata}{invoice_number} 
    \hfill \JSONParseValue{\invoicedata}{date}
    
    \bigskip
    
    \noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ @{} l X r r r @{} }
        \toprule
        item ID & item description & unit price & unit & price \\ 
        \midrule
        \ListMapInline{0,1}{%
            \JSONParseValue{\invoicedata}{items_sold[#1].item_ref_code} & 
            \JSONParseValue{\invoicedata}{items_sold[#1].item_description} &
            \JSONParseValue{\invoicedata}{items_sold[#1].item_unit_price} &  
            \JSONParseValue{\invoicedata}{items_sold[#1].item_quantity} &           
            \ItemTotal{#1}{ 
                \JSONParseExpandableValue{\invoicedata}{items_sold[#1].item_quantity} *
                \JSONParseExpandableValue{\invoicedata}{items_sold[#1].item_unit_price} 
            } \NewlineOrRule{1}{#1}
        }%
        \textbf{total} & & & & \textbf{\InvoiceTotal} \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    
    \bigskip
    
    \noindent Please pay the full amount until \JSONParseValue{\invoicedata}{Due by} 
    to the following bank account:
    
    \noindent \JSONParseValue{\invoicedata}{general_details.my_bank_IBAN} at 
    \JSONParseValue{\invoicedata}{general_details.my_bank_name} 
    
\end{document}



Nice package! An answer to this fairly popular question using jsonparse might be nice for people perusing the site in the future

Jasper, thank you so much. This is awesome!

I created the JSON support for OpTeX just now. It is presented as OpTeX trick 0154. I tested it with your example and create the following text for OpTeX. I add it here just for comparison with LaTeX approach.
\fontfam[lm]

\def\execenode#1{\immediateassignment\global\sdef{\the\opt}{#1}}
\def\startinode{\trycs{i.\the\opt}{}}

\sdef{i.items_sold}#1\stopinode{\def\items_sold{#1}}
\def\repeatit #1#2{\ea\ignoresecond\ea\foreach#1\do{\exectree{##1}#2}}

\jsonread \invoice {invoice.json}
\wterm{\showtree\invoice}  % only for logging purpose
\exectree\invoice           % processes data

\newcount\invoicenum
\def\price{\edef\tmp{\expr[2]{\item_quantity*\item_unit_price}}%
   \xdef\total{\expr[2]{\total+\tmp}}\tmp}
\def\fmtnum#1{\ea\ignoreit\the\numexpr #1+1000\relax}

\incr\invoicenum \def\total{0}
\title\ \name\ \surname \par
\address
\vskip 1cm
\centerline{Invoice No. \fmtnum\invoicenum \hfill \date}
\medskip
\table pxto\hsize{lp{\tsize}rrr}{\cr
   itemID             & item description  & unit price       & units          & price \crl
   \repeatit \items_sold
      {\item_ref_code & \item_description & \item_unit_price & \item_quantity & \price \cr}
   \crl
   \bf total &&&& \bf\total \crl
}
\bigskip
\noindent Please pay the full amount until \cs{Due by}
to the following bank account \my_bank_IBAN\ at \my_bank_name.

\bye

The meaning of these macros are explained in OpTeX trick 0155.
Moreover, when you create a modification of the invoice.json file which includes data of more invoices in the JSON format:
[{ data of 1-st invoice },{ data of 2-nd invoice },...,{ data of n-th invoice }]

then you can set the macro above to a single macro (for example \singleinvoice) and the loop over all invoices in from the JSON file can be implemented by:
\sdef{i.JSON}#1\stopinode{\def\JSONlist{#1}}
\jsonread \invoice {invoice.json}
\exectree\invoice
\repeatit\JSONlist {\singleinvoice \vfil\break}
\bye


In the my example above, specifically the json file, I had  two items sold. Hoever, I could have had more then that (or even less). This would require an approach that would dynamically parse the items of items_sold, looping over them.
In that respect, I have decided to craft my own solution, using lua.
The lua code I am using for this is:
\luaexec{%
%Import some abracadabra, needed for reading json, avail on the internet
local json = require("dkjson")
%
%Set path file and name - and read it
local file = io.open("\invoicePath\THEINVOICEFILE", "r")
local jsonString = file:read("*a")
file:close()
%
%Parse it
jsonData = json.decode(jsonString)
%
%Start table env.
tex.print("\\begin{invoicetable}")
%
%Loop over sold items
for _, Theitem in ipairs(jsonData.items_sold) do
  local ref = Theitem.ref
  local Description = Theitem.Description
  local shortName = tostring(Theitem.shortName)
  local unitPrice = Theitem.unitPrice
  local units = Theitem.units
  %
  %Define over each iteration (as it changes...)
  tex.print("\\def\\ref{" .. ref .. "}")
  tex.print("\\def\\descr{" .. Description .. "}")
  tex.print("\\def\\short{" .. shortName .. "}")
  tex.print("\\def\\units{" .. units .. "}")
  tex.print("\\def\\unitPrice{" .. unitPrice .. "}")
  tex.print("\\def\\Description{" .. Description .. "}")
  %Write the table, populating dynamically
  tex.print("\\invoiceitem{[\\ref]}{" .. shortName .. "}{" .. units .. "}{" .. unitPrice .. "}{}")
end
%Close the table
tex.print("\\end{invoicetable}")
%
}

I realized, after some head scratching, that lua does not like empty lines (a line cannot start with empty field...).
By so doing, I can maintain a sort of database in json (human readable for accountants that don't seem to like LaTex very much). My *.tex and *.cls files, take good care of the json file, transforming that into a nice looking, sleek, and duly compiled invoice. Also, if needed, I can look back and recompile old invoices. Additionally, I engraved invoice REF, payee Name and project name into the PDF metadata.
